# Fwrite write only 4096 instead of 100,000 bytes

Tags: c, linux, embedded, fwrite, stdio

I use fwrite to write a buffer of 100,000 chars to file, but the return value from fwrite is only 4096.

```
char  buffer  [100000];
memset(buffer,0x00,100000);  
FILE *f = fopen("<path>","ab+");
if(f ==NULL)
{
return;
}
int ret =fwrite(buffer,1,100000,f);
printf("ret = %d",ret);
```

ret = 4096

Why this code write only 4096 bytes instead of 100,000 ?

This is Linux embedded system

Comment: @NateEldredge In general, if no error happens `fwrite` should write what it is told to. One can try `ferror` on the file to see if there is any.

Comment: That linux filesystem

Comment: `char * buffer  [100000]` -> `char buffer[100000]`. But this doesn't explain your problem.

Comment: I edit my post,

Comment: 100k on stack is a little scary...  Try moving your buffer to global space and try again just to be sure you aren't doing something UB with stack size.

Comment: yes, `fwrite` return 4096 ,

Comment: Could you please post your full [mcve] with `include`s and `main`? Did you include `stdio.h`? Do you get any compiler warnings when compiling? How are you compiling the code?

Comment: Is it an embedded system?

Comment: yes, it is linux embedded system

Comment: Then, what system is it? What implementation of `fwrite` and of C standard library are you using? glibc? musl? Which version of it?

Comment: Try N = 1, 100, 10000.  Do though behave well?

Comment: I suspect the 1) file system of running out of room or 2) stack overflow.

Comment: I'm pretty sure to have seen something similar in the past. Embedded system, of course. Unfortunately I cannot find any proof, nor I'm sure about any architectural explanation. Not enough for providing a full answer, at least. But think about it: it is absolutely reasonable that there is a structural limit to file i/o in system that are basically based on physical buffers.

Comment: Furthermore in embedded systems we don't have disks but flash memories. And among them NAND flash memories are particularly slow in reading: a set of commands has to be provided in order to perform a read, and the data is made available after a certain amount of time. This can be quite a long task, so probably it is reasonable setting an upper limit to the chunk.

Comment: Finally, if I remember correctly, reads are limited to the size of a sectors, and `fwrite` could be limited to exactly that chunk. **In conclusion**, if OP's system is based on a NAND flash memory with a sector/page size of 4kb, then we have an answer.

Comment: You may need to use an iterative `multi_fwrite()` function that iterates over the buffer, writing what it can and trying again where the write is short.  I have a version for file descriptors and `write()` — revising it to work with file streams is not hard: `ssize_t multi_write(int fd, const char *buffer, size_t bytes) { ssize_t nb = 0; size_t nleft = nbytes; ssize_t tbytes = 0; while (nleft > 0 && (nb = write(fd, buffer, nleft)) > 0) { tbytes += nb; buffer += nb; nleft  -= nb; } if (tbytes == 0) tbytes = nb; return tbytes;
}`. You'd need to review `ssize_t` vs `size_t`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler your iterative solution is surely gold, and the definitive fix for this issue, but OP is wondering _why_ there is this limitation.

Comment: And there are reasons why comments are not answers, @RobertoCaboni, and that's one of them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I apologize, but I was curious to read an explanation too. :)

Comment: @RobertoCaboni: I strongly suspect that 'system limitations' (especially in embedded systems) — as you suggest — is the correct answer.  There's a moderate chance the system's documentation mentions it.  However, I have no experience with such systems so I can't pontificate on the 'why' issue; the best I can do is show roughly (it's rough mainly because of formatting limitations in comments) how to work around the problem.  There's no indication from the OP that they're aware of this possibility, so I added a comment that might help them.

Answer (score 1):

[From man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> [...] If an error occurs, or the end of the file is
>              reached, **the return value is a short item count (or zero).**

In this case you should use `ferror(f)` to see if the file handle is in error condition. Also, you can zero the `errno` before the call, and print the error message with `perror`:

```
errno = 0;
int ret = fwrite(buffer, 1, 100000, f);
if (ret != 100000) {
    printf("Stream error indication %d", ferror(f));
    perror("Short item count");
}
```

Comment: _"If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero)"_ Yes, but it doesn't mean that _**"If the return value is a short item count (or zero) an error occurred"**_.

Comment: I don't think Ir is setting `errno`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. we do not know. The code above *is* a way to know.

Answer (score -1):

The maximum length for any `write` call is defined by `SSIZE_MAX` which can be found in `unistd.h`.

This holds for every POSIX-compliant system. `SSIZE_MAX` may differ for different implementations.

Try out the following example to determine the maximum write length on your system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("SSIZE_MAX : %ld\n", SSIZE_MAX);
  return 0;
}
```

It prints `SSIZE_MAX : 9223372036854775807` on my machine.

EDIT: You can also try to locate your `limits.h` file, but compiling might be the easier option

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, so I cannot read in other people's minds, but you answered to the question _"what is the theoric limit to data that can be written by fwrite?"_. The question actually is _"Why did MY fwrite only write 4096 bytes?"_